# mysql: where write order clause in join structures?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-order-by

Let's assume I have three table - `list`,`a` and `b`

```
table list
|a_id|--|b_id|--'name'
|4   |--|3   |--|foo|
|1   |--|2   |--|foo|

table a
|id|--|name|--|order|
|1 |--|a_1 |--|1    |
|2 |--|a_2 |--|2    |
.....................
|n |--|a_n |--|n    |

table b
|id|--|name|--|order|
|1 |--|b_1 |--|1    |
|2 |--|b_2 |--|2    |
.....................
|n |--|b_n |--|n    |
```

`a_id` in table `list` is id from `a` table, and

`b_id` in table `list` is id from `b` table

I need to get the name list from `a` and `b` tables ordered by their order, where `name` = 'foo' in `list` table.

ie. i need to get `a_1`,`a_4` from table `a`, and `b_2`,`b_3` from `b`.

I wrote a query like

```
SELECT
                    `a_1_table`.`name` a_1_name,
                    `b_1_table`.`name` b_1_name
                FROM
                    `list`
                LEFT JOIN 
                    `a_1` AS a_1_table ON ( `a_1_table`.`id` = `list`.`a_id` )
                LEFT JOIN 
                    `b_1` AS b_1_table ON ( `b_1_table`.`id` = `list`.`b_id` )
                WHERE 
                    `list`.`name` = 'foo'
```

but as I see, in such structure, I can't write `order by ...`. ie. I can' but I will not get what I want.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT x.name
    FROM (SELECT a.name, a.order, 1 AS sort
            FROM LIST l
            JOIN a ON a.id = list.a_id
          WHERE l.name = 'foo'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT b.name, b.order, 2 AS sort
            FROM LIST l
            JOIN b ON b.id = list.b_id
           WHERE l.name = 'foo') x
ORDER BY x.sort, x.order
```

`UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`, because it doesn't remove duplicates (which `UNION` does).